# I can't create a book under Internet Explorer 7

Tags: 6

I can't create a book under Internet Explorer 7; when I click "add a new book" in Book outline, the browser shows, "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer blocked this site from downloading files to your computer. Click here for more options…."

When I click on "Download the file," the file name is "form8c01710d," and it contains `{ "status": false, "data": "" }`.

Comment: Sounds like just another IE problem you have there. Might I suggest upgrading your browser to something newer (Firefox or Chrome or IE9)? In any case I don't think this question belongs on drupal.stackexchange.com as it is not an issue with drupal, but much rather the configuration of a really old browser on a really old OS

Comment: when i updated it to IE8. this error still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is an issue that continues into modern versions of IE as well.

If your site has the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module running, http://drupal.org/node/860966 speaks of the issue; the real issue is found in comment #6.

The only reason I am following up on this post here is that it is has a high in Google search,  and I figured others are looking for how to solve the issue.